# How to use SQL MAX(SUM()) function

Tags: sql, sum, max, sqlplus

I need some help using the SQL `max` and `sum` aggregate functions in SQL.

I want to display the first and last names of employees who have put in the most number of total hours on projects. And I want to list the employees with the highest total combined project hours.

I have two tables:

```
employee: 
FNAMEM--LNAME--SSN--BDATE--ADDRESS--SALARY--SUPERSSN--DNO

works_on:
ESSN--PROJECT_NUM--HOURS
```

This is what I have so far but there is a syntax error in the code:

```
select fname, lname, max(sum(hours)) "Total Hours", essn
from employee, works_on
where essn = ssn
order by lname;
```

I know that `max(sum(hours))` does not work, what will give me the right result?

Comment: you need to add a `group by fname, lname` for aggregate functions... and `order by lname, sum(hours) desc`... i dont think `max(sum(hours))` works, though

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: sorry this is sql plus

Comment: How about `ORDER` + limiting result set with 1 row?

Comment: I can't use ORDER because there are multiple instances of the MAX value, the query needs to list all employees with total project hours equal to the MAX hours.

Comment: How many employees per project? What if two (or more) worked the same greatest amount of hours?

Comment: there are various multiple employees per project, there are multiple employees each with the max total hours value, they all need to be listed.

Comment: It will help if you post some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: `SELECT name FROM employee 
WHERE  id = (

 #getting id of employee
 SELECT idemployee FROM (
  SELECT idemployee, SUM(amount) x FROM bonus 
  GROUP BY idemployee
        #getting max:
  ORDER BY x desc
  LIMIT 1) sub
 );`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use a group by if you are going to use the aggregate function `sum`.

Something like this;

```
SELECT s.fname, s.lname 
FROM (SELECT fname, lname, SUM(w.hours) SumHours, w.project_num 
      FROM Emplyee e 
      JOIN Works_on w ON  w.essn = e.ssn 
      GROUP BY e.fname, e.lname, w.project_num) s
WHERE s.SumHours = (SELECT MAX(w.hours) MaxSum
                    FROM Works_on w1 
                    WHERE  w1.project_num = s.project_num)
```

Note that subqueries embedded in the where clause invoke a massive performance penalty.

Comment: Thank you, I had to make a couple minor adjustments but you were right on the money. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT s.fname, s.lname 
FROM (SELECT fname, lname, SUM(w.hours) SumHours
      FROM employee e 
      JOIN works_on w ON  w.essn = e.ssn 
      GROUP BY e.fname, e.lname) s
WHERE s.SumHours = (SELECT MAX(hours) MaxSum
                    FROM works_on w1);
```

This code worked for me; Thanks to user: PM 77-1 for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

try this:   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4f9e/2/0

```
select emp_hours.* 

from  (  select  ssn, lname, fname,
                 sum(hours) as total_hours 
          from   emp as e 
                 join wo as w on e.ssn = w.essn
          group  by ssn, lname, fname ) as emp_hours 

      join (   select  essn, 
                       sum(hours) as sum_hours 
               from    wo 
               group   by essn 
               order   by sum_hours desc  
               limit   1) as hours_by_emp
         on emp_hours.total_hours = hours_by_emp.sum_hours
```

Comment: Selecting `essn` isn't likely to work, since it's neither an aggregate nor a `group by` column.

Comment: That is correct syntax, but it lists all employee names rather than only listing those employees with the maximum total project hours. That is what is tripping me up, I need only the max(sum(hours)) but that is not a valid function.

Comment: top people, I know from the table that there are multiple instances of the MAX value. They all need to be listed.

Comment: okay... so say max(hours) is 60 and there are 3 people with 60 hours... you need those 3 names, then?

Comment: what field is the employee id?

Comment: ssn / essn is the employee ID. and yes if the max is 60 and three people have the max, I need those three listed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT e.fname, e.lname, w.total_hours, e.ssn, 
    rank() over (order by w.total_hours desc) as rnk
FROM employee e INNER JOIN
(SELECT essn, SUM(hours) total_hours
 FROM works_on
 GROUP BY essn) w
ON e.ssn = w.essn
where rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of simplicity I would simply fetch the max value in a separate query and use a second query to fetch those with the sum matching the max value. The data being retrieved from the first query is a single number so there is little overhead. The database cannot optimize much more if you construct a single query. The only downside is the latency between completion of first query and start of second query.

Ignore the following, it does the wrong thing.

<s>something like:</s>

```
select fname, lname, max(sum_hours) "Total Hours", essn
  from (select fname, lname, sum(hours) sum_hours from employee, works_on
  where essn = ssn group by fname, lname, works_on)
  group by fname, lname
  order by lname;
```

basically you first construct the sum temporary table and then do a max on it

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right (you need one "best harworking" person on project), I believe the next query should do it (with the best perfomance):

```
SELECT FNAMEM, LNAME, TotalHours
FROM    (
        SELECT PROJECT_NUM, ESSN, MAX(HOURS) TotalHours
            FROM works_on 
            GROUP BY PROJECT_NAME
        ) mx
        JOIN
        employee
        ON SSN = ESSN
   ORDER BY LNAME;
```

Please, test and confirm (or not), I wanna know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `having`, like this:

```
SELECT column1, column2, sum(column3)
FROM table
WHERE column4 = 'value'
GROUP BY column1, column2
HAVING sum(column3) = max(column3)
ORDER BY column1;
```